# If product is in parent category, do something in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Right now I'm trying to find out if a product is in a specific parent category, if it is - it will display an image. Parent category 67 is the parent category, as shown below.

Home > 67 > 22 > 1

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
```

And

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 67) { ?>
-show image-
<?php } ?>
```

So far it works only for products inside 67, but not products in the sub categories with 67 as its parent

Comment: It's never a good thing to hardcode category id like that. You can easily add system config option to select the desired category. To answer your question, you should look into category `path` field. It should help you find the descendants of your category.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. You can get product parent category and if it is the desired category do what you want to do.

```
if ($product->getCategory()->getParentCategory() == 'your_desire_category'){
    //your code
}
```

Where `$product` can be retrieve by

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```